# Can I point a subdomain to an Apache server and the main domain to an IIS server?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, iis, azure

Suppose I have 'example.com' and want it to be pointing to an IIS server, to reach my ASP app. Can I also have sub.example.com pointing to an Apache server (physically on a different computer, with different IP) to serve a web document? How can I do it? I want to do this with Azure and Digital Ocean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do. You can run any child domain (sub-domain ) on a different server using different web server application (Apache,IIS etc). All you can do is create a sub-domain (A record) in your registrar provided control panel for your main domain and point to the IP where your sub-domain web-server is running.

Also make sure that your ServerAlias (in case of Apache server), as your subdomain fqdn name. It should be same for other web-servers configuration.

Comment: You can run them off the same IP if that IP address points to a reverse proxy capable of distributing the traffic to the actual servers rather than connecting directlty. Indeed such an architecture will allow multiple servers where the content is differentiated by other aspects of the request (the path, the authenticated username, a cookie, the browser....)